# using multiple templates on the same popover button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to user multiple templates for [bootstrap popover](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers) , the scenario I follow is click on button on load page, first template will be shown with a link to change class f popover button. So it should display the second template when I click on the same button again ! but it seems popover save the class for button and binding the popover on it. I tried to destroy it and bind popover again on the new class but not work. find example on fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Lx7es96z/).

I've a solution by replace the button html with the same button but with the new class. and It worked. see here working example I made. [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Lx7es96z/1/)
but I'm trying to find another or better solution .

```
var popoverTemplate = ['<div class="first-pop popover" role="tooltip">',
            '<div class="arrow"></div>',
            '<button type="button" class="close" onclick="$(\'.popover\').popover(\'hide\')" aria-hidden="true">×</button>',
            '<h3 class="popover-title">test</h3>',
            '<div class="popover-content">ONE',
            '</div>',
            '</div>'].join('');

        var firstTemplate = ['<div class="firstTmp-pop popover" role="tooltip">',
            '<div class="arrow"></div>',
            '<button type="button" class="close" onclick="$(\'.popover\').popover(\'hide\')" aria-hidden="true">×</button>',
            '<div class="popover-content">',
            '</div>',
            '</div>'].join('');

        var firstTmpContent = ['<div class="firstTmpContent-post clearfix"><a class="changetemp" href="#">Change template</a>',
            '</div>',].join('');

        var content = ['<div>Content</div>',].join('');

var secondOptions = {
            trigger: "click"
            , html: true
            , template: popoverTemplate 
            , content: content

        };

var firstOptions = {
            trigger: "click"
            , html: true
            , template: firstTemplate
            , content: firstTmpContent

        };

 $('.box').popover(firstOptions);
 $(document).on('click','.box2',function(e){
    $(this).popover(secondOptions);
 });

$(document).on('click','.changetemp',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('[rel="popover"]').popover('hide'); 
    $('.box').removeClass('box').addClass('box2');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var obj = '';
$('.box').click(function(){
    obj = $(this).clone();
});
$(document).on('click','.changetemp',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('[rel="popover"]').popover('hide'); 
    obj.addClass('box2').removeClass('box');
    $('.box').replaceWith(obj);
    $('.box2').popover(secondOptions);
});
```